# Creating all possible playing cards (a deck)

Tags: java, collections

Let's say I'm trying to simulate playing with standard playing cards.

I have something like this:

```
class Face {
  Set<Character> Faces = new HashSet<Character>(
      Arrays.asList('2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J', 'Q', 'K', 'A')
  );
}
```

and something like this:

`public enum Suit { HEART, DIAMONDS, SPADES, CLUBS }`

How would I create a collection, such as a set or linked list, of objects that collection is best suited for this, and what type of object each pair in the collection should be.

Comment: best appoach would be a class "Card" with two members: face and suit

Comment: @progressive_overload Yes, but how would I generate a collection of 52 Card objects, covering all possible permutations?

Comment: two loops: outer one for Suit, inner one for face.. gives you 52 card objects. put them in a List or Set depending on if order matters.

Comment: Comments on how to improve the quality of my question would be appreciated. I know how to do this in one way, I'm asking which way is the BEST way in practice.

Comment: i think you will find lots of people with different solutions... each claiming to have the best :D...

Comment: Why did my question get so many downvotes? How can I improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as @Progressive_overload commented, this would probably be the best approach.

Card Class:

```
enum Suit {HEART, DIAMONDS, SPADES, CLUBS}
enum Rank {TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE}
class Card {
   public Rank rank;
   public Suit suit;

   public Card (Rank r, Suit s) {
     rank = r; suit = s;
   }
}
```

Generate:

```
List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();

for (Suit s : Suit.values()) {
  for (Rank r : Rank.values()) {
    deck.add(new Card(r, s));
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how would I generate a collection of 52 Card objects, covering all possible permutations?

Comment: @GFauxPas like that?

Comment: That is not valid java

Comment: It doesn't even compile.

Comment: Yes it is and yes it does... you even copied the entire code and posted it as your own answer @xenteros

Comment: It's a common pattern. Believe or not I have already used such enums in the past. After your edit it actually compiles. I would edit your answer but it would be against the [so] rules as it would change completely your answer - from not compiling to correct one. Very unfortunate.

Comment: @xenteros and you just happen to write everything in the exact same order, with the exact same capitalization and variable names..

Comment: @Olian04 I got suggested by your answer. I don't deny

Comment: @xenteros ctrl+c, ctrl+v, then you added a toString Override... well done. I don't deny it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good pattern to make `enum` of suits, `enum` of ranks and then loop through `enum#values`.

Olien04 has [suggested a similar approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38850909/19679) but his code didn't compile. For this reason I've added this answer based on his, with a constructor and toString method.

```
enum Suit {HEART, DIAMONDS, SPADES, CLUBS}
enum Rank {TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE}

public class Card {
    Rank rank;
    Suit suit;
    public Card (Rank r, Suit s) {rank = r; suit = s;} //public constructor
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return rank.toString() + " " + suit.toString();
    }
}

ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();
for (Suit s : Suit.values()) {
    for (Rank r : Rank.values()) {
        deck.add(new Card(r, s));
    }
}
System.out.println(deck.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks, I have just done poker for my student project :)

Comment: But that is just a list of *cards*, the question is asking for *pairs* of cards.

Comment: The `.values` was what I was missing from my knowledge, thank you!

Comment: @GFauxPas I added `toString()` method and debug `println()` so you can print the whole deck in a beautiful way.

Comment: @Konrad no, I didn't ask the question clearly, I meant each card is a pair, and there are 52 possible pairs.

Comment: @GFauxPas feel free to accept my edit request - it makes the question easier to understand.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that by ordered pair (a,b) you mean that a.face<=b.face and that you don't want pairs with two times the same card. You just need a nested loop where you iterate over all values where that condition is true and add them to a list (so you preserve the sort order value of each pairs first card as well for easier verification).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CardPairs
{

    static char[] faces = {'2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J', 'Q', 'K', 'A'};
    static enum Suit { HEART, DIAMONDS, SPADES, CLUBS };

    static class Card
    {
        final char face;
        final Suit suit;

        public Card(char face, Suit suit) {this.face=face;this.suit=suit;}
        @Override public String toString() {return face+" "+suit;}
    }

    static public class CardPair
    {
        final Card first;
        final Card second;

        public CardPair(Card first, Card second) {this.first=first;this.second=second;}
        @Override public String toString() {return "("+first+", "+second+")";}
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        List<CardPair> allPairs = new ArrayList<CardPair>();
        for(int i=0;i<faces.length;i++)
            for(int j=i;j<faces.length;j++)
                for(Suit suit1: Suit.values())
                    for(Suit suit2: Suit.values())
                    {
                        {
                            if(suit1!=suit2||i!=j) // assuming you don't want pairs of the same card
                            {
                            allPairs.add(new CardPair(new Card(faces[i],suit1),new Card(faces[j],suit2)));
                            }
                        }
                    }
        System.out.println(allPairs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats so much nested loops.

Comment: That is the strangest downvote I have ever gotten :-) The number of nested loops is inherent in the problem.

Comment: didn't downvote... but why 4 loops? 2 would be enough

Comment: I don't think the question was asking about pairs of cards; it seems like the "pairs" referred to are the suit, face value tuple. So the question is just asking how to build a collection of the 52 cards in a deck.

Comment: @Michelle Ahh, then I totally misunderstood the question. That explains why I need more loops then the other solutions. I am not a native speaker but I think the question is very ambigous still. I would refer to a "suit, face value tuple" as "card" :-) And "ordered pair" does not make sense in that context because a pair is a tuple is always ordered, so I thought it would mean a pair where the first element is <= the second element.

Comment: It is ambiguous, no worries.

Comment: @KonradHöffner my apologies